# Preview data from MySQL through drop down list generated from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

So I already have a drop down list generated from a MySQL db.
The problem I can't solve is how to display a "preview" of a selected option.

It's a part of a game I'm building, and you can go to the "arena".
In the arena, there will be a drop down list of opponents to choose from, all of them have different values attached to them like, name, level, strength and so on.
So if you select "opponent 1" from the list, I want a opponent preview to show, and if I change the drop down to "opponent 2" I want the preview to update.
When the player has decided to fight that opponent, a submit can be made by clicking my "fight" button.

Here is the drop down list I'm using:

**EDIT:** See my answear below with updated code.

Comment: example roytuts.com/dependent-dropdown-example-in-php-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After like 8h of pulling my hair, google and ALOT of reading.. i manage to put this together, and it is working!

HTML code:

```
<div id='load_npc'>
    <table width='720' border='0' align='center'>
        <td align='center'>
            <form id='form1' name='form1' method='post' action=''>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend><strong>Pick your opponent!</strong></legend>
                    <p>
                        <select name='npc_name' id='npc_name'>
                            <option value='' selected='selected'> Select an opponent..                              </option>
                            <option name='row[name]' value='row[name]'><php_row></php_row>                          </option>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <input type='submit' value='Fight!' \>
                    </p>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </td>
    </table>
    <div id='results'></div>
</div>
```

Javascript code, placed in the header:

```
 $(function() { //  document.ready
     $("#npc_name").on("change", function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: "system/npc_load.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: {
                 npc_name: $(this).val()
             },
             success: function(data) {
                 $("#results").html(data);
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

And here is the php file referd to by my script:

```
<?php
require ("database.php");

    $npc_name = $_POST['npc_name'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM npc WHERE name = '" . $npc_name . "'";
    $myData = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    //count if there are any results
    $numrow = mysqli_num_rows($myData) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    if($numrow == 0)
    {
        echo "No results found.";
    }
    else
    {
    echo '<fieldset><legend><strong>Information</strong></legend><p>
            <table width="auto" height="172" border="0">
            <tr><th>Name</th></tr>
            <tr><th>Type</th></tr>
            <tr><th>Level</th></tr>';
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
    {
    echo "<form action='system/npc_load.php' method='post'>";
    echo"<tr>"; 
    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['name'] . "<input type=hidden name=name value=" . $info['name'] . " </td>";
    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['type'] . "<input type=hidden name=type value=" . $info['type'] . " size='11' maxlength='11' /> </td>"; 
    echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['level'] . "<input type=hidden name=level value=" . $info['level'] . "' /> </td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
    echo "</form>";
    }
    }
    echo "</fieldset>"; 

    ?>
```